# Redux store out of order for check email exists feature

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I am trying to make a feature that checks if an entered email is already taken with `redux`. I am not sure as to why my store's state seems as if it is 1 state behind. I suspect it might be a race condition from my promises but I am not sure as to where this is occurring. This is why my store's state changes value later on and also why the developer tool's outputs are out of order.

Scenario 1:

1. Enter in email that is taken:

   > ```
   > {}                    <-- expected {exist: true}
   > value: true
   > ```
2. Enter in email that is taken:

   > ```
   > {exist: true}
   > value: true
   > ```
3. Enter in email that is NOT taken:

   > ```
   > {exist: true}         <-- expected {exist: false}
   > value: false
   > ```
4. Enter in email that is NOT taken:

   > ```
   > {exist: false}
   > value: false
   > ```

Sometimes the outcome of the same steps in scenario 1 are different:

Scenario 1 (different outcome):

1. Enter in email that is taken:

   > ```
   > {}
   > value: true
   > ```
2. Enter in email that is taken:

   > ```
   > value: true
   > {exist: true}
   > ```

Notice how the order of the output in the developer tools is different.

Scenario 2:

1. Enter in email that is NOT taken:

   > ```
   > {}                    <-- expected {exist: false}
   > value: false
   > ```
2. Enter in email that is NOT taken:

   > ```
   > {exist: false}               
   > value: false
   > ```
3. Enter in email that is taken:

   > ```
   > {exist: false}        <-- expected {exist: true}
   > value: true
   > ```
4. Enter in email that is taken:

   > ```
   > {exist: true}
   > value: true
   > ```

Component method:

```
checkEmailExist(event) {
    const email = event.target.value;
    if (email !== "") {
      this.setState({isEmailTaken: "pending"}, () => {
        this.props.actions.checkEmailExist(email).then(() => {
          console.log(this.props.isEmailTaken);
        }).catch(err => {});
      });
    }
  }
```

`mapDispatchToProps` used to allow access to all my actions. Contains `checkEmailExist` action

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {actions: bindActionCreators(createAccountActions, dispatch)};
};
```

`mapStateToProps` used to place store state into `this.props`, specifically, `isEmailTaken`

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    createdAccount: state.createdAccount,
    isEmailTaken: state.isEmailTaken
  };
};
```

`checkEmailExist` action:

```
export function checkEmailExist(email) {
  const headers = new Headers({"Content-Type": "text/plain; charset=utf-8"});
  const options = {method: 'GET', headers};
  return dispatch => {
    return fetch(`${apiEndpoints.CHECK_EMAIL_EXIST_ENDPOINT}/${email}`, options).then(res => {
      if (res.ok) {
        res.json().then(v => {
          console.log("value: " + v);
          return dispatch(emailExists(v));
        });
      } else {
        console.log("res no okay");
      }
    }).catch(error => {});
  };
}
```

`emailExists` action:

```
export function emailExists(v) {
  return {
    type: (v ? types.EMAIL_EXISTS : types.EMAIL_DOES_NOT_EXIST)
  };
}
```

Reducer:

```
export default (state={}, action={}) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case types.EMAIL_DOES_NOT_EXIST:
      return {exist: false};
    case types.EMAIL_EXISTS:
      return {exist: true};
    default: return state;
  }
};
```

All Reducers are connected with:

```
export default combineReducers({
  isEmailTaken,
  ...
});
```